# What kind of plant is my little plant here?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

[image: Picture of plant]

(Please forgive the Instagram format -- it's the best picture I have of it!)

ETA: I'm thinking maybe it's a leggy *Kalanchoe*?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it looks like a leggy *Kalanchoe blossfeldiana*. Most people throw them out when the blooms fade after purchase,but if you want to keep it, cut it  right back ('d take it down to half an inch on any thick and leggy stems) repot into new potting soil if it needs it, or give it a feed with a houseplant fertilizer and stand it in a bright daylight position. Water only when the surface of the soil feels dry,and water thoroughly, emptying out any outer tray or pot  30 minutes later so the plant is not left sitting in water. If you do repot it, water it in thoroughly immediately afterwards,then wait for it to dry out and water as  advised ongoing. These plants need to be kept a little drier in winter, but should be watered enough that the leaves don't start to shrivel or wrinkle.